# Python API for GCP Sub billing account

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Do we have any direct Python method for creating GCP sub billing account under master billing account? I used the below API request but it seems to be a wrong method.

```
request = service.billingAccounts().create(displayName='testapi')
```

Signer is created using below method, where google service is "cloudbilling"

```
signer = crypt.RSASigner.from_string(key.strip())
credential = service_account.Credentials(signer, principal, google_token_uri)
service = build(googleservice, version, credentials=credential, cache_discovery=False)
```

I tried googling a python method to create sub billing but unable to find it.

Comment: I think you need to specify the master billing account as the parent resource.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudbilling/latest/google.cloud.billing_v1.services.cloud_billing.CloudBillingClient#google_cloud_billing_v1_services_cloud_billing_CloudBillingClient_create_billing_account) with you, in which you will find a python method to create a sub billing account.

Note that when creating a subaccount, the current authenticated user must have the billing.accounts.update IAM permission on the master account, which is typically given to billing account administrators https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access. This method will return an error if the master account has not been provisioned as a reseller account.

Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you but I'm new to python and the method looks very confusing to me

Comment: If you struggle to use this method, I suggest you to raise a new question (since the original question is already replied with the proper way to do this in python). To raise a proper coding question here, there is some guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which, among other things, suggest to provide things that you've already tried. The exercise to ask a good question for that specific method will also help you in understanding better the library and its usage (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) for the reason why this is useful).